# How to Compare two arrays objects with nested objects?

Tags: android

I am writing a test case where i need to compare two array objects which contains a nested objects. Here is the sample code please check.

```
Class TestGeoNames {

    private Status status;
    public void setStatus(Status lstatus) {
        status = lstatus;
    }
    public Class Status {
        private String mesg;
        private String value;

        public String getMesg() {
            return mesg;
        }

        public void setMesg(String mesg) {
            this.mesg = mesg;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the testCase Code:

```
List<TestGeoNames > result = NetworkManager.executeByJSON(request, TestGeoNames .class);

    List<TestGeoNames > Cacheresult = CacheManager.getResponseFromCache(request);

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertNotNull(Cacheresult);

    TestGeonamesBean[] tgb = new TestGeonamesBean[0];
    TestGeonamesBean[] cacheResultArray = result.toArray(tgb);
    TestGeonamesBean[] resultArray = Cacheresult.toArray(tgb); 

    assertEquals(true, Arrays.equals(resultArray, cacheResultArray));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `equals` to work on custom object you have to override `hashCode()` and `equals(Object o)` from `Object` class